# ActiveRecord, can I validates a has_and_belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

Yesterday, I was crazy because I couldn't do the validations in model, using a `many-to-many` relationship on ActiveRecord on Rails 4.1.6.

I tryed to use this gem: `gem 'deferred_associations'` suggested by: [this blog](http://mikrobi.github.io/validating-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations-with-rails-3/)
but did not succeded.

So I kill the MVC feelings... I did the validation in controller... :/
But for now I changed the relation and the business logic of my application.
But the question still stay with me.

Can someone explain to me how validates on `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation it's possible?

My regards!

**UPDATE 01** to @User089247

```
     # My logic is simple: A question should has 3 or less answers.
     # A answer can be used in many questions.


     validates_associated :answers, if: :has_more_space?

      private
      def has_more_space?
        if answers.size > 3
          true
        else
          errors.add(:answers, "You can't do that!")
          false
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all of you that try to help me, but with time I have read the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many), and I discovered this part:

> You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks,
>   or extra attributes on the join model.

In other words, I was trying to do in the wrong form!

For now I know, if you don't  need to validate anything or else, use the `has_and_belong_to_many` because it's more simple and easier to use!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed to see [`validates_associated`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated) method in [Active Record Validations guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-associated).

Here is an example:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors

  validates_associated :authors
end
```

Make sure that you:

> Don't use validates_associated on both ends of your associations. They
>   would call each other in an infinite loop.

Since, what you're looking for is not exactly validating presence of an association, `validates_associated` won't work in your case. `validates_associated` validates the association's presence. For validating the count of associations your model can have, you'll have to create a custom validation like this:

```
validate :maximum_answers

private
def maximum_answers
  errors.add(:base, "You can't add more than 3 answers.") if self.reload.answers.count >= 3
end
```

Comment: I didn't find that! :/. Did you use once? Some different methods to create your own validations?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get you. Did you use once?: *Yes, and it works.* Some different methods to create your own validations?: *No, it's just how I have mentioned in example.*

Comment: Because I want to validate (using your example) eg. : Allow add a new author ONLY with the registers in the relation table `books_authors` is 3 or less.

Comment: This doesn't work for me :/ I updated my question with I tried :D

Comment: @BrunoCasali : See the updated answer. You should have mentioned about validating maximum number of associations count you can have, not validating the association itself. Both are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a custom validation

```
#in Author class

validate :must_have_3_books_or_less

def must_have_3_books_or_less
  if self.books_authors.size > 3
    self.errors.add_to_base("Author is required to have 3 books or less")
  end
end
```